# Dynamically set URL for Webservice target with NLog 5

Tags: .net, nlog

I have a Webservice target in my NLog.config file, but I want the target URL to have the base URL of that app. I see this should now be possible with NLog 5:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target---Workaround-for-url-variables

I cannot find an example of how to do this though?

Would love to be able to do something like this:

```
<target xsi:type="WebService"
            name="webhook"
            url="${aspnet-request-host}/mypath/senderror"
            protocol="HttpPost"
            encoding="utf-8"
            >

    <parameter name="error" type="System.String" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}: ${level} - ${message}"/> 

</target>
```

Comment: Notice [${aspnet-appbasepath}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-AppBasePath-layout-renderer) returns the ContentRoot - Absolute path to the directory that contains the application content files. Not sure that directory-path will be good web-service-url. If you are trying to call a web-service-method on the host-application itself from a NLog target, then you will probably enter a world of hurt.

Comment: oops, I added the wrong variable, meant to put ${aspnet-request-host} (fixed the question) which i believe would get the base URL of the webapp.. Is that how it would be done just by placing the variable in the url parameter?

Comment: Notice [${aspnet-request-host}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetRequest-Host-Layout-Renderer) returns the hostname that started the web-request. Ex. the hostname of the web-browser. If you are trying to call a web-service-method on the host-application itself from a NLog target, then you will probably enter a world of hurt.